# GridView trying to select the whole row except the last column?

Tags: c#, gridview, webforms

I currently have this function attached to my gridview I am tring to get it to avoid the 11 column I have created. I is a hyperlink that triggers this function rather than going to the hyperlink provided any help would be appreciated.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(TakeGrid, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think a better approach would be to identify some field/property from your ````e.Row.DataItem```` to determine whether or not to hide.  Is it always going to be the 11th row, or just this time?

Comment: I want to avoid the 11th Column not Row, I have a hyperlink on the 11th column that I cant use whilst the whole row is bound

Comment: Are you trying to hide the ````<asp:HyperLink>```` that has an ````id=lnk```` ?

Comment: No I have a row of data the hyperlink needs to lead to a different web site. I want the user to be able to click on any other column and trigger a code behind function. The hyperlink should always be visible

Answer (score 0):

This event will fire whenever you will create a new row in gridview and if you want to specifically avoid the 11th row then just use the and condition with rowindex property.

```
    protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = 
        Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(TakeGrid, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
       e.Row.Cells[11].Attributes.Remove("onclick");
      }
    }
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid the 11th column. I want to bind the data to get the seperate id from each row. However I dont want to bind the 11th column as it is a hyperlink and i cant click it if the whole row is bound

Comment: This still isn't allowing me to click the hyperlink. when i click it the hyperlink it fires the next function instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this..... target that HyperLink in the RowDataBound event.  You are using a lot of BoundFields, which is fine, but this is another means to target a control for each specific row when you're binding.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            HyperLink link = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("lnk");

            if (link != null)
            {
                link.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

On your front-end, you need to add the event to the GridView....

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
</asp:GridView>
```

Here is also another example to get the DataItem for the GridView and then execute logic.  I created a sample `MyProduct` class, and imagine that the DataSource for my GridView is a `Collection<MyProduct>()`.

```
    public partial class MyProduct
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string sku { get; set; }
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            MyProduct rowData = (MyProduct)e.Row.DataItem;

            if (rowData != null)
            {
                // only hide link if property for product meets our logic
                if (string.Equals(rowData.sku, "MySkuProduct", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {

                    HyperLink link = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("lnk");

                    if (link != null)
                    {
                        link.Visible = false;
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not what I was asking. I wanted if I cound unbind the 11th column. I want to be able to click the hyperlink without triggering any code behind I do not want to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys I have found the answer to my question and have realised I was asking the wrong question. Instead of leaving the 11th column out I just applied the onclick to the rows I wanted it to be attached to. e.g.

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[i].Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(TakeGrid, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
                }
            }
        }
```

but thanks to everyone for your help. and here is a link to another similar question I used for the answer.

[Gridview row clickable except for first column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781861/gridview-row-clickable-except-for-first-column)